# Getting started with byebug in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I am making my way from Django to Rails. So far I just created a new Rails app and found in the `Gemfile` this line:

```
  # Call 'debugger' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a
  # debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
```

How this supposed to work? Is it as straightforward as it said in the comment? I can put `debugger` somewhere in code and get a debugger console in my browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

start rails server

```
rails s
```

and monitor the logs.

[image]

Now try accessing the page which points to the place where `debugger` is written in the code
The log will stop at a point where you have put the `debugger`/`byebug` word.

[image]
You can print out variables at that instant

**update for rails 4**

On suggestion of Deivid, I would like to quote him here

> drop the --debug flag. You don't need to do anything special to make
>   byebug work in Rails 4. Just require 'byebug' and call byebug

Comment: Notice that the `--debug` flag is deprecated and does nothing in Rails 4. Byebug is not started until you call the `byebug` method.

Comment: @deivid thanks for the heads up , I wanted to update the commands but couldnt find any rails 4 specific information here https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug :)

Comment: @aelor Just drop the --debug flag. You don't need to do anything special to make byebug work in Rails 4. Just `require 'byebug'` and call `byebug`.

Comment: When you say "print out variables", do you mean use the display command?

Comment: @AdrianMann I know I am late but let me answer the question. You can use puts <variable name> to print out the variable

Answer (score 2):

You won't get a debugger in your browser - calling `debugger` or `byebug`  will drop you into the byebug prompt in the terminal window that was used to run your rails server (note that this is not the same as the rails console - there is a overview of what you can do in the [rails debugging guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-byebug-gem)).

Another tool you may be interested in is the [web-console](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/web-console/2.1.2) gem (included by default in rails 4.2 and above). This allows you call `console` (in a controller, view etc.) and will dump you into a browser based IRB session at that point